# CLOC- count lines of code, exclude everything in a dir except for certain files

Tags: cloc

I am using [cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) to count our code.  We need to exclude everything in a directory, except for files with a specific form like *instru.c.  Is it possible to use the exclude and include files to do this?